# JavaScript display property only affects the first 3 elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a ***Filter Vanilla JS*** project and it only changes `.display` property for the first 3 elements and does nothing for the other ones.
Below the corresponding HTML and JS codes can be found as well.

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Filter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><button class="btnAll">All</button></li>
            <li><button class="btnCakes">Cakes</button></li>
            <li><button class="btnCupcakes">CupCakes</button></li>
            <li><button class="btnSweets">Sweets</button></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <main>
       <img src="1.jpg" class="cake">
       <img src="2.jpg" class="cupcakes">
       <img src="3.jpg" class="sweets">
       <img src="4.jpg" class="cake">
       <img src="5.jpg" class="sweets">
       <img src="6.jpg" class="cake">
       <img src="7.jpg" class="cupcakes">
       <img src="8.jpg" class="cupcakes">
       <img src="9.jpg" class="sweets"> 
    </main>

    <script src="main.js">

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS code:**

```
const btnAll = document.querySelector(".btnAll");
const btnCakes = document.querySelector(".btnCakes");
const btnCupcakes = document.querySelector(".btnCupcakes");
const btnSweets = document.querySelector(".btnSweets");
//
const cakes = document.querySelector(".cake");
const cupCakes = document.querySelector(".cupcakes");
const sweets = document.querySelector(".sweets");

const pressAll = ()=>{
    cakes.style.display = "block";
    cupCakes.style.display = "block";
    sweets.style.display = "block";
}

const pressCakes = ()=>{
    cakes.style.display = "block";
    cupCakes.style.display = "none";
    sweets.style.display = "none";
}

const pressCupCakes = ()=>{
    cakes.style.display = "none";
    cupCakes.style.display = "block";
    sweets.style.display = "none";
}

const pressSweets = ()=>{
    cakes.style.display = "none";
    cupCakes.style.display = "none";
    sweets.style.display = "block";
}

btnAll.addEventListener("click", pressAll);
btnCakes.addEventListener("click", pressCakes);
btnCupcakes.addEventListener("click", pressCupCakes);
btnSweets.addEventListener("click", pressSweets);
```

Thank you in advance.
I am truly sorry if I made a stupid mistake and was not able to spot it.

Comment: [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) selects a single (the first) element. Not all of them.

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: and then you need to loop over it all, somebody posted a question already:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get your `cakes, cupcakes and sweets` using the following approach:

```
var cakes = document.getElementsByClassName("cake");
```

and when you need to change any styling to all of the elements with the class name of `cake`, you should loop through all the cakes and change their styling:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < cakes.length; i++) {
  cakes[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have more than one element with class cake, cupcakes and sweets, you need to get a *collection* of those elements (e.g. with `querySelectorAll`) and then some iteration over those collections.

For example:

```
const cakes = document.querySelectorAll(".cake");
const cupCakes = document.querySelectorAll(".cupcakes");
const sweets = document.querySelectorAll(".sweets");

const pressAll = ()=>{
    for (let item of [...cakes, ...cupCakes, ...sweets]) item.style.display = "block";
}

const pressCakes = ()=>{
    for (let item of cakes) item.style.display = "block";
    for (let item of [...cupCakes, ...sweets]) item.style.display = "none";
}

//...etc...etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use querySelectorAll and set the display accordingly.

```js
const showByClassName = (name, show) => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll("." + name)].forEach(elm => elm.style.display = show ? "block": "none");
}

document.querySelector(".btnAll").addEventListener("click", () => {
  showByClassName("cake", true);
  showByClassName("cupcakes", true);
  showByClassName("sweets", true);
});
document.querySelector(".btnCakes").addEventListener("click", () => {
  showByClassName("cake", true);
  showByClassName("cupcakes", false);
  showByClassName("sweets", false);
});
document.querySelector(".btnCupcakes").addEventListener("click", () => {
  showByClassName("cake", false);
  showByClassName("cupcakes", true);
  showByClassName("sweets", false);
});
document.querySelector(".btnSweets").addEventListener("click", () => {
  showByClassName("cake", false);
  showByClassName("cupcakes", false);
  showByClassName("sweets", true);
});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><button class="btnAll">All</button></li>
        <li><button class="btnCakes">Cakes</button></li>
        <li><button class="btnCupcakes">CupCakes</button></li>
        <li><button class="btnSweets">Sweets</button></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <main>
      <img src="1.jpg" class="cake">
      <img src="2.jpg" class="cupcakes">
      <img src="3.jpg" class="sweets">
      <img src="4.jpg" class="cake">
      <img src="5.jpg" class="sweets">
      <img src="6.jpg" class="cake">
      <img src="7.jpg" class="cupcakes">
      <img src="8.jpg" class="cupcakes">
      <img src="9.jpg" class="sweets">
    </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a little mistake in your code, you used [`document.querySelector()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) to get all Elements, but [document.querySelector](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) only takes the first element. The right function is [`document.querySelectorAll('.myClass')`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) or [`document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) and then you have multiple elements selected. Those you can handle with by a for loop. Here is an example function.

```
function displayAll(objList, value){
    for(var i = 0; i < objList.length; i++){
        objList[i].style.display = value;
    }
}
```

Here one of your onclick function revised:

```
const pressSweets = ()=>{
    displayAll(cakes, "none");
    displayAll(cupCakes, "none");
    displayAll(sweets, "block");
}
```